# Comparing Value on Submit Vs Database

Tags: php, mysql, warnings

**The "dbcred.php" class**

```
<?php
   # pdo_testdb_connect.php - function for connecting to the "test" database

   function testdb_connect ()
   {
     $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=dbname", "root", "");
     return ($dbh);
   }
?>
```

**PHP**

```
<?php
#connect mysql
require_once "dbcred.php";
$dbh = testdb_connect ();

session_start(); 
$username = $_POST['regduser']; 
$userpass = md5($_POST['regdpass']); 
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Student WHERE regduser= '$username' AND regdpass = '$regdpass'");

if (mysql_num_rows($result)!= 1) {   $error = "Login failed"; 
 #include "loginform.php"; 
} else { 
 $_SESSION['username'] = "$username"; 
 $_SESSION['ip'] = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']; 
 #include "membersection.php"; 
}
?>
```

**HTML**

```
  <form action="inc/check_regUsr.php" method="post" id="userLogon">
        <div class="field required">
        Username: <input type="text" name="regduser" tabindex="1" /><br />
        </div>
        <div class="field required">
        Password: <input type="text" name="regdpass" tabindex="2" /><br />
        </div>
        <input type="submit" name="submitUser" />
    </form>
```

When I try to submit valid credentials it says: **Warning: mysql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in on line 12**

Why does it not like this and how can I fix it?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Student WHERE regduser= '$username' AND regdpass = '$regdpass'");
```

I don't know how your database class is working. So I will write a general mysql connect code.

```
mysql_connect($host,$username,$password);
mysql_select_db($db);
```

No you can execute the query.

Comment: Neither of these work, I dont think it has to do with that line. Its whining about the line starting with the "-->" I put above. See above updated.

Comment: Right! Because the $result parameter must be a resource. It's boolean false in your case. The last line of code in my comment should do the job. If you still see errors, let me see the page on your server.

Comment: See updated php code above. Html hasn't changed. Its still whining about the line 'if (mysql_num_rows($result)!= 1) {   $error = "Login failed"; ' which i understand is either 1 or a 0, thoughts?

Comment: If you are not going to use dbcred.php class, you must make a mysql connection and select the database. Check my updated code.

Comment: But, I am using dbcred.php class for my db connection.....? Why isn't this class working with the (mysql_num_rows ... ?

Comment: I think this is a waste of time. Is that a class that everyone SHOULD know? I just see the name of the file, dbcred.php, but I don't see the class.

Comment: See the updated code, i added the contents of 'dbcred.php' to it.